# Usage of magic mover app

Tags: attachment, files

Hi all I am using a magic mover app to move files from notes and attachments to files and it works fine. Is there any way if I install this app all the existing records notes and attachments would get converted to files without any action?

I checked and found a negative result. In that case is there any other app I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what you mean by "without any action".  Are you saying you want to it run automatically, with no user clicks?  Why would you want to do this?  Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on researching.

[image]

It is possible to obtain all the files for a specific time range and we can convert them to files.